# servo control using a microcontroller and separate power supplies

Tags: arduino, servo

I'm trying to get a very basic servo control circuit to work using an Arduino and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I've got separate 5V power supplies for the microcontroller and the servo, grounds are connected (through the microcontroller) and decoupling capacitors in place.

Schematic:[image: Schematic]

Breadboard: [image: Breadboard]

Code running on Arduino:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

void setup() {
  servo.attach(10);
}

void loop() {
  servo.write(135);
  delay(500); 
  servo.write(45);
  delay(500);
}
```

I've tried:

- Two different Servos, both "standard" servos rated for 4.8-6V. One servo is the HobbyTech YM-2765, it just clicks and doesn't move as though underpowered. Another servo, the 3001HB, will work for up to a few minutes and then get "stuck", pushing it slightly will resume the movement.
- Two different Arduinos
- Different values for decoupling capacitors - 1000uF, the standard 470uF I see recommend in many places, with or without the small 100nF capacitor.
- Powering both servo and arduino from the same power supply.
- Different 5V power supplies - both the wall and 2 different 5V USB "power bricks" designed for mobile phone charging. Wall power supply rated for 1.8A, power bricks are rated for 1A, 2.1A, or 2.4A, I am using a hacked/cut open USB cable to supply power.
- Different servo movement code running on the Arduino (more time to move).

Would really appreciate any tips on troubleshooting or what I could be doing wrong! Thanks.

Comment: meaure all voltages. thech that thr 5v supplies are making 5V and if possible that the servo output (from the arduino)  is making pulses.

Comment: Most likely the problem is the breadboard.  They aren't intended for high current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell your circuit and code are correct, so the most likely culprit is bad power.

The YM-2765 is a high power servo that could draw over 2A when moving. The 3001HB is a standard power servo that probably draws 1A or less.

It's possible that your power supplies are not up the job. [Many cheap USB power supplies cannot deliver their rated load](https://lygte-info.dk/info/usbPowerSupplyTest%20UK.html), or can't do it for an extended period of time. When a USB power supply overloads it usually goes into current limiting, which drops the voltage to stop current increasing until the overload is removed. Some have 'fold-back' current limiting that greatly reduces the current, so if the servo ever stalls it won't get enough current to start moving again.

For testing I suggest replacing the servo power supply with a 4 cell AA alkaline or NiMH battery. 'Hobby' servos are generally designed to work from this power source when used in radio control models. If that still fails then look at your wiring. If you are using a breadboard, replace it with a proper servo socket and soldered connections.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've edited my post to clarify that I don't just mean USB wall chargers but those big "power bricks". Poor power would explain both issues; so will try a 4 cell alkaline power supply first; if that doesn't work will try soldering connections. To make sure I understand, if the wiring is poor, it wouldn't be able to deliver enough power to the YM-2765, right? But I'm not sure how bad wiring could cause the issue i'm seeing with the 3001HB, in which it (reproducibly) works for a several minutes before stopping/stalling. Any chance you could explain or point me to relevant docs?

Comment: Ultimately, this issue seems to have been caused by two failures at once: one in the 3001HB servo, and one in the the breadboard, found by replacing everything and substituting back in parts from the malfunctioning circuit. Have soldered everything up and YM-2765 is now working perfectly well.